# JS Chrome top.document

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

What is Chrome's equivalent of 'top.document', valid in both FF and IE8.

In Chrome, 'top' is valid, top.length returns 2 (frames)...as it should.  But top.document returns 'undefined'. Needed to get an element.  top.document.getElementById(id) works perfectly in both FF and IE8.

Thanks in advance,
swk

Comment: Works for me. Test case?

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer's late, but this has been driving me crazy, and the issue, it seems for me anyway, is simply because my page wasn't actually hosted.  It was just a prototype laying in a network folder.  If the page is hosted on a server, it works fine.

What even made it worse, is that Chrome wouldn't evaluate anything after that security exception was thrown.  Took me forever to figure out why I couldn't see any of my global variables.

I was able to get around the second issue at least, by surrounding the stuff that touches top in a try/catch block so that any other Javascript would still evaluate. This is enough for me, for prototype purposes, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
if (top.document == 'undefined')
{
   top.document = window.top.document || null;
}
```

Also ive just tested in my chrome browser and top.document returns the actual document so not sure, what version are you using !

Comment: Hey, thanks for that, but no go.  Version is 5.0.375.55.

'window.top' and 'top' are identical. alert() on both yields 'object DOMWindow'. But its 'document' is 'undefined'.

Any other thoughts?
-swk

Comment: Im currently on the same version so I cant understand how your getting  undefined. See: http://a.imagehost.org/0651/to_document.png

Comment: The JS console is giving me: "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file; Domains, protocols and ports must match"
(not a problem with IE8 or FF)

Is this giving anyone a clue as where to look next?  Thanks...  -swk (robert: thanks for hanging in)

Comment: Ok so i think this problem is down to Cross Domain Origin, This is a security precaution taken by browsers to stop your site being manipulated with things such as cookies etc i believe. Somehow you have to tell the frames that they can be access by the parent frame. Here is an article regrading this issue. http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes Also try look googel for "Iframes and ajvascript" "Iframes security with cross domain". Also google use a method of making this work with the HTTP-Headers but im not fully sure about that. Im sure this is the problem tho. Regards

Comment: So, as I understand that article, the idea is to set the 'top' URL via, “parent.frames[1].location.href=correctURL", after which 'top.document' should then be be able to yield its elements.

Hmm.  Let me give it a shot, and I'll get back.  Thanks,  -sk

Comment: No dice.  The browser goes to an all white screen, and locks up.

Comment: Is there other way you can do this without using frames, I also noticed that your awaiting responses on the Google chrome deb team, any response from them yet ?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily mind adopting the scrolling <div> method, and i might yet go that route, but this is really a shortcoming in Chrome. IE8, FF, Safari and Opera pose no difficulty. Here's what I'm doing successfully in those four:

frm= top.document.getElementById("frmset"); 
if ( firefox() ) // etc.
   {  frm.rows= "24.0%, *" ;}

Comment: No, nothing yet from the Chrome people.  Thanks for hanging in.