# chrome unable to get top.document after changing url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

*I am not using any plugins or frameworks.*

I have some local help pages (which will not be hosted on a server), most of which need to be loaded into a frame.  So, during`onload`, I check if the page is in a frame or not:

```
top.document.location.href == document.location.href
```

and if this is true, and therefore the page is not in a frame, then I

```
top.document.location.href = "frame.html?info="+document.location.href;
```

Now, when `frame.html?info=stuff.html` loads, I can get the `info` parameter from:

```
`top.document` or `window.top.document`
```

and load that page into a frame as intended.

This all works as intended on Safari, IE9, and Opera.  It **does not work in Chrome**.  Instead, `top.document` and `window.top.document` are both `undefined` after frame.html is loaded.

How should I get the top URL and, more importantly, its parameters when I load `frame.html?info=...`

If it is helpful, I believe this behavior is because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937118/js-chrome-top-document).

Comment: Can you store the location in a variable beforehand?

Comment: @dave -- when I load a new page (top.document.location.href = ...) won't I lose the variable?